# SFCC update payment instruments using REST API

Tags: rest-api, commerce-cloud

As mentioned in the [API Explorer](https://api-explorer.commercecloud.salesforce.com/) with version 21.3 For the Update payment instruments API i.e

```
PATCH /sites/{site_id}/orders/{order_no}/payment_instruments/{payment_instrument_id}
```

The sample request mentioned in the documentation is

```
payment_instrument_update_request{
description:    
Request body to update an order payment instrument.
}
```

When I tried to update it using API, the error is thrown as below.

What are the correct input properties for this API?

[image]